# Strange garage door sensors

Tags: garage-door-opener

In my 2 car garage, a box was moved close to door #1. The sensors for that door remained normal (solid sensor lights). However, the red sensor for door #2 started blinking and that door (#2) would not operate. It seems strange that a blockage on one door would cause the other door to malfunction. What could be causing this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info to help you: what make/model of garage door opener? do the sensors on door 2 stop door 1? is this repeatable?

Comment: The garage door opener is a Overhead Door Python 2. With a box blocking the sensors on Door #1, the red and green sensors remain steady. Door #1 opens OK using the keypad. The red sensor then starts blinking and I cannot close the door using the keypad. Meanwhile, on Door #2, the red sensor blinks and the door cannot be opened or closed with the keypad even tough there is nothing blocking the sensors. Makes no sense that the blocked sensor on Door #1 causes Door #2 to become inoperable. Or maybe I'm just going nuts!

Comment: Does blocking the sensor door #2 (Hello, Monty Hall!) cause door 1 to behave the same? Might you just have the sensors reversed?

Comment: Daniel - I tried what you suggested, but door #1 does work fine with door #2 sensor blocked.

Comment: Lol, Monty Hall, always change your answer!

Comment: Did you install the sensors as shown in the manual, with the two red-LED units (the light sources) between the two doors and the two green-LED units (the sensors) on the sides?